# C# user control as a custom panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I create my own user control which only contains a panel :

When I drag a myPanel object in the designer and then try to add a button on it, the button is in fact added to the form's controls.

Is there a property/attribute I must set in order to perform this, an other way to do what I want ?

```
public class MyPanel : UserControl
{
    private Panel panelMain;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panelMain = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panelMain
        // 
        this.panelMain.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
        this.panelMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panelMain.Name = "panelMain";
        this.panelMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.panelMain.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // myPanel
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(this.panelMain);
        this.Name = "MyPanel";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look here

[How to make a UserControl object acts as a control container design-time by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813450)

But if you only need extended Panel functionality its better to inherit directly from Panel.

Comment: It is what I what looking for . About inheritancy, I just made the problem simpler and of course I needed something more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, I do the following :

```
[Designer(typeof(myControlDesigner))] 
public class MyPanel : UserControl
{
    private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    private Panel panelMain;
    ...

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Panel InnerPanel
    {
        get { return panelMain; }
        set { panelMain = value; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TableLayoutPanel InnerTableLayout
    {
        get { return tableLayoutPanel1; }
        set { tableLayoutPanel1 = value; }
    }
}
```

With myControlDesigner for [Designer(typeof(myControlDesigner))] to be

```
class myControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {

        base.Initialize(component);

        MyPanel myPanel = component as MyPanel;
        this.EnableDesignMode(myPanel.InnerPanel, "InnerPanel");
        this.EnableDesignMode(myPanel.InnerTableLayout, "InnerTableLayout");

    }

}
```

(Other source : [Add Control to UserControl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7d06efff-db69-4ae3-a6d5-43028911ea95) )

Comment: I have used your approach for creating a custom panel.  But, when I use this custom panel in another user control, when I drag controls on the panel in the designer, they initially appear.  But, when I recompile, they disappear.  They are still there but it seems the custom panel is draw over/after them.  Did you have this sort of problem?  I am using VS 2005/.NET 2.0.

Comment: No I don't remember having this kind of issues, do you have a small sample ?

Comment: @bsh152s This is a very old answer but I wanted to chime in about the 'controls are lost' problem:  The Panel/TableLayout that is exposed must be publicly exposed (public modifier).  In my usage of this code, I also added [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] to ensure Visual Studio serializes the changes.